# Optimal desktop configuration for using sculpting?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, sculpting

I'm using blender for quite long time but performance was never was an issue in polygonal modelling. However, once I started sculpting using higher resolution in "Multi resolution" modifier my desktop is getting slowdown and also sometimes hanged. Could anyone let me know the optimal configuration of PC for using sculpting tools in Blender ?

Comment: Do you have to use multiresolution modifier? Dynamic topology sculpting may have a better performance.